# how to gray out files from .gitignore in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

is it possible to gray out files, which are in .gitignore in Project perspective?
I've tried to find this setting in PHPStorm config, also I've tried to make a new scope with another scheme color, but probably it is not possible to make a scope using .gitignore.

Comment: Can you share the configuration/scheme approach you have attempted?

Comment: What configuration/scheme do you think about?

Comment: doesn't seem to be possible currently, please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116425

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can install a plugin called .gitignore

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495

Comment: The plugin is now called `.ignore`
(cannot edit because SO disallows such small changes… why?!)